# Run Python Script with Bash - null-object doesn't work

Tags: python, bash, shell

I've got this following script which converts pdf-files with a python-script
My python-script has three inputs: pperation-key input-file output-file.
The operation-key can have the value null, 1, 2.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.pdf
do
    outputdir="`pwd`/${f%.pdf}_out.pdf"
    inputdir="`pwd`/$f"
    python <myscript> "null" $inputdir $outputdir
done
```

In the terminal it the python-script works with the following inputs, but not in the shell-script:

```
python convertpdf.py  null /Users/admin/test.pdf /Users/admin/test_out.pdf
```

How can I deliever a null object with the script?

Comment: It's not a _object_, it's just a parameter passed to `python`.  Your script doesn't work for some other reason.  You need to elaborate _doesn't work_.

Comment: You better put `$inputdir` and `$outputdir` in double quotes when passing them to python, for the likely case that any of your `*.pdf` file names contain spaces.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means that terminal display me, that a parameter is missing.

Comment: You're passing the string "null", not any other meaning of NULL. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the missing double quotes!

Now the following script works perfect!

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.pdf
do
    outputdir="`pwd`/${f%.pdf}_out.pdf"
    inputdir="`pwd`/$f"
    python <myscript> "null" "$inputdir" "$outputdir"
done
```